# npm install handlebars -g ERRORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, npm, handlebars.js

So I'm on OS X 10.9.3 and just tried to install handlebars.js via NPM in terminal.

i run `npm install handlebars -g` as instructed by the documentation http.://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html (had to add a "." to avoid exceeding 2 hyperlinks, not enough rep)

then, I get the following results -- http://pastebin.com/RbMHZwKV (my username replaced with [Username] btw)

then, just to check if it's installed (though it seems not to be), i try `npm list -g`
and it results in -- http://pastebin.com/DBGHVwGF

seems that there's some dependency on another package named optimist, maybe? Or do I just need to run the precompiler? pretty confused but new to this stuff

Please advise me on what my next step is...

Comment: Use [`sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo). [Permissions when Using npm to Install Other Stuff](https://github.com/npm/npm#permissions-when-using-npm-to-install-other-stuff)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm install handlebars -g
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm install -g` tries to put whatever package you're installing in `/opt/local/lib/node_modules/`.  Your regular use doesn't have permission to modify this directory (and thus the error).

Instead, you need the super user to do it.  We tell the super user to do something by adding `sudo` at the beginning of the command:

```
sudo npm install -g handlebars
```

For more information about system permissions when installing packages globally, look here: https://github.com/npm/npm#permissions-when-using-npm-to-install-other-stuff